# Dealing with Negative Numbers in Strings

Tags: javascript, regex, math

I have a simple, but perplexing problem, with Math.

The following code will take a number from a string (usually contained in a span or div) and subtract the value of 1 from it.

`.replace(/(\d+)/g, function(a,n){ return (+n-1); });`

This works really well, except when we get below zero. Once we get to -1 we're obviously dealing with negative subtraction.

`-1 - 1 = -0

-0 - 1 = --1`

how can I avoid this? It's likely I've got a general problem with the math here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your function is not treating "-1" as negative one - it's being treated as a hyphen followed by positive 1.

`/(-?\d+)/g` will capture a leading hyphen as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.replace(/(\d+)/g)` isn't capturing the leading `-`. 
If you want your addition to be correct, you'll need something like `/(-?\d+)/`.